# C# Abrir y cerrar conexion MySql

Tags: c#, mysqli, visual-studio

Estoy usando el siguiente código para hacer una consulta en una base de datos la cual abre otro form si la consulta tiene resultado o muestra un mensaje si no.

```
using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=estacionamiento2;Uid=root;pwd=;"))               
{  
  conexion.Open();    
  MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("select * from usuarios where usuario = '" + ustxt.Text + "' and password = PASSWORD('" + textBox1.Text + "')"));
  MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
  if (reader.Read())                 
  {
    Form1 frm = new Form1(); 
    frm.Visible = true;                 
  }              
  else                 
  {                    
    MessageBox.Show("Datos erroneos");        
  }             
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al ejecutar la consulta me marca un error en `MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();` pues me marca un error de que la conexión debe ser abierta, aún cuando ya la abrí anteriormente

Comment: Sugiero ENCARECIDAMENTE, como otros te lo dirán, que no debes utilizar las queries sin sanear su input. Así como está el código, serás víctima de una [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Comment: Ya he tomado en cuenta eso, para evitar inyecciones de código

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tengas un problema en el armado de tu cadena de conexión.
Algún parámetro podría estar mal para ello te comparto el uso de esta clase `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` para el armado de una cadena de conexión de manera que sea más fácil.

Podrías utilizar esta clase exclusivamente para manejar tu base de datos

```
    public class Connection
    {
        public MySqlConnection con;
        public long insert_id;

        public Connection()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                b.Server = "localhost";
                b.UserID = "root";
                b.Password = "root";
                b.Database = "estacionamiento2";
                con = new MySqlConnection(b.ToString());
            }
            catch (MySqlException me)
            {
                throw me;
            }
        }

        public void execute(String sql)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = this.con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            this.con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.con.Close();
            this.insert_id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
        }

        public void executeQuery(string sql)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = this.con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            this.con.Open();
        }
    }
```

El método executeQuery es para realizar consultas

y el método execute es para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados o funciones de mysql.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Cómo responde esto la pregunta de OP?

Answer (score 0):

Pude notar que no estás asignando la conexión a `MySqlCommand`.

```
using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=estacionamiento2;Uid=root;pwd=;"))               
{  
  conexion.Open();    
  MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("select * from usuarios where usuario = '" + ustxt.Text + "' and password = PASSWORD('" + textBox1.Text + "')"));
  
  
  comando.Connection = conexion;  // <----- Agrega esta línea


  MySqlDataReader reader = ...

  //Código omitido para mantener el foco en el área de interés
}
```

También puedes utilizar el constructor de [`MySqlCommand`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand__ctor_2.htm) que recibe como parámetros la instrucción sql y la conexión.

**Recomendaciones:**

- En relación a los objetos `MySqlCommand` y `MySqlDataReader` deben ser descartados (Dispose) bien sea de forma implicita (*dentro de un bloque `using` tal como tienes la conexión*) o de manera explicita invocando su método `Dispose()` en el bloque `finally` de un `try-catch-finally` o `try-finally`.
  *Esta recomendación aplica para cualquier clase que implementa la interface `IDisposable`.*
- Para saber si un `MySqlDataReader` contiene registros, es mejor utilizar la propiedad [`reader.HasRows`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_HasRows.htm).

Siguiendo estas recomendaciones tu código puede escribirse de la siguiente manera:

A partir de **C# 8** puedes utilizar el patrón de [declaración using](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using)

```
using MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=estacionamiento2;Uid=root;pwd=;");               
using MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("instruccion sql", conexion);

try
{
    conexion.Open();
    using MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)                 
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1(); 
        frm.Visible = true;                 
    }              
    else                 
    {                    
        MessageBox.Show("Datos erroneos");        
    }             
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //instrucciones cuando ocurre un error
}
```

En cualquier versión de **C#**

```
using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=estacionamiento2;Uid=root;pwd=;"))  
using (MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("instruccion sql", conexion))
{
    try
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using( MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)                 
            {
                Form1 frm = new Form1(); 
                frm.Visible = true;                 
            }              
            else                 
            {                    
                MessageBox.Show("Datos erroneos");        
            }
        }  
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //instrucciones cuando ocurre un error
    }               
}
```

- Por favor ten en cuenta el comentario de @Arriel relacionado con la [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)